# qbo3 Process Parent change and Security

Tags: qbo3

I have several `Process` records in `qbo3` that were mapped to an incorrect parent record; that is, they were set up as children of an incorrect `Loan` record.

After updating the `Process.ObjectID` record to point to the correct `Loan`, the external users that have access to that `Loan` cannot access the loan's child `Process` records.

What is the root cause, and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

The `qbo3` extranet security model (which controls access for external users) creates an access control list (ACL) upon creation of a record, and *assumes that child records do not change parents*.

After changing a parent record, you can reset the ACL with the following API call:

```
/api/objectaccess/resetbyobject?Object=Loan&ObjectID={Your Loan ID}&Execute=1
```

To preview what records will be impacted:

```
/api/objectaccess/resetbyobject?Object=Loan&ObjectID={Your Loan ID}
```

> Note that you must reset the ACL from the parent record. If you attempt to reset from your `Process` record, the parent (`Loan`) ACL records will not be affected.